# plotly error bar plot strange color scheme

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I am observing a strange choice from `plotly::plot_ly` to color the error bars when a group coloring is specified:

```
library("data.table")
library("plotly")
dat <- data.table(
  low_diff = c(2, 3, 1)
  , high_diff = c(3, 4, 1)
  , point = c(10, 11, 9)
  , type = LETTERS[1:3]
)
plot_ly(data = dat, y = type, x = point, mode = "markers", color = type,
        error_x = list(type = "data", symmetric = FALSE,
                       array = high_diff, arrayminus = low_diff))
```

[image]

How can I specify that each point should have the same color as its error bar?

Comment: @Jota Post as answer?

Comment: @Jota yes, definitely is, go ahead and post and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have `color = type`, switch to `group = type` to get the desired grouping.

```
plot_ly(data = dat, y = type, x = point, mode = "markers", group = type,
        error_x = list(type = "data", symmetric = FALSE,
                       array = high_diff, arrayminus = low_diff))
```